# How to use command line arguments

Tags: vb.net, command-line-arguments

I have a console application which reads .txt files. I want to be able to drag a txt file over my app and it would automatically open my app and show the text files contents. I think I have to use command line arguments like this:

```
Sub Main(ByVal cmdArgs() As String)

End Sub

Sub ReadFile(FilePath as String)

End Sub
```

But how can I pass the text files path to my ReadFile sub?

Comment: http://averagecoder.net/passing-arguments-to-your-vbnet-console-application.htm

Comment: If it's a console app, how do you expect it to respond to drag and drop?  Also, if you're dragging the file over the app, the app must already be open.  So why do you need to open your app?

Comment: @Eyal It works, and the app doesn't have to be opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what I had to do is read the first argument like this:

```
Sub Main(cmdArgs as String())
  ReadFile(cmdArgs(0))
End Sub
```